# Using BING Webcontrol V8 from VB6 IDE

Tags: vb6, bing-maps

We have a large system written in VB6, one part of the system uses a WebControl to present the user with a BING map. This is using the V7 of the BING webcontrol. Microsoft have deprecated the V7 control so I'm trying to migrate to V8 but I'm having some problems.

The Bing WebControl V8 requires IE11 (although it does work on IE10), but the WebControl by default only uses the IE7 rendering engine. You can tell it to use a later engine (if available) by writing a registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\<exe name> REG_DWORD 11000
```

That works fine when the program is compiled, but doesn't work when running from the VB6 IDE, so debugging is a PITA. I've set both the compiled EXE name and also VB6.EXE in the registry, but it doesn't work within VB6.

Any ideas as to how I get the WebControl to use IE10/11 rendering when running within the IDE? This is on Windows 7 btw.

*EDIT*

Here is my code:
Add a WebBrowser control to a form, call it msIE.

```
    Option Explicit

Private mstrHTTP As String
Public mstrAPI_Key As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Caption = "Name : '" & App.EXEName & "'"

    mstrHTTP = ""
    mstrAPI_Key = "Your BING API key here"

    msIE.Navigate ("about:blank")

    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "<html>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "    <head>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge' />")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <title>Load map with navigation bar module</title>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <meta charset='utf-8' />")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        ")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <!-- Reference to the Bing Maps SDK -->")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <script type='text/javascript'")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap'")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                async defer></script>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        ")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <script type='text/javascript'>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        function GetMap()")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        {")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                credentials: '" & mstrAPI_Key & "'")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                ,enableInertia: false")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                ,showMapTypeSelector: false")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                ,showZoomButtons: false")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "                ,showLocateMeButton: false")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "            });")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        // Add post map load code here")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        }")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        </script>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "    </head>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "    <body style='margin:0;'>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "        <div id='myMap' style='width:100%;height:100%;'></div>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "    </body>")
    Call BuildFunction(mstrHTTP, "</html>")

    msIE.Document.write (mstrHTTP)

End Sub

Private Sub BuildFunction(ByRef theString As String, ByRef extraString As String)
    theString = theString & extraString & vbCrLf
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
    msIE.Top = 0
    msIE.Left = 0
    msIE.Width = Me.ScaleWidth
    msIE.Height = Me.ScaleHeight
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, for some reason I've come back to this after the weekend, and it works fine. Nothing changed that I can think of, it just now works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the header of your HTML page:

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`

This will tell the Web Control to use the latest version of IE installed on the machine.

Comment: I have already tried that, it makes no difference when running within the VB6 IDE.

Comment: Then you will have to either edit the registry as described here https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version or use a different web browser control, there may be a version of Chromium around that works on VB6.

Comment: As I stated in the original question I have already tried that registry entry. It works for the compiled EXE, but not whilst running in debug within the IDE.